# Is it possible to share HAML templates between Coffeescript (Backbone.js) and Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, haml

Is this possible? I know people use mustache to share templates, but can you use HAML? I would prefer pre compilation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search turns up [this lib for client-side rendering of HAML](https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js) . So it would appear that yes, you could share templates between the client-side and server-side of your app.

If you are processing your JS templates server-side first, then the asset pipeline will take care of this with the correct file extension. You wont be able to use the rendered haml template on the client-side though as it will be missing its tags..